# Separating large sets of data by single criteria

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

My goal is to write a macro that will take the data (This is just a sample of what it will be like) and group each row by the shift number (Shift 1,2,3).

Essentially this sheet will become a database for data recorded in our plant so its row dimension will be dynamic.

Ideally I would be able to find a way for excel to recognize the 3 different shifts, select their respective rows and separate them with a 1 row offset where the data can be easily manipulated from there.

My initial thought was to import all of the data, filter it by each criteria, then copy and paste at an offset, but that is not working.

The code I posted below was just a test to see if the filter method would work. Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Columns("A:J").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$51").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Shift 1"


Range("A8:J10").Copy
Worksheets("Sorter").AutoFilterMode = False
Range("A20").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Columns("A:J").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$51").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Shift 2"


Range("A8:J10").Copy
Worksheets("Sorter").AutoFilterMode = False
Range("A25").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Columns("A:J").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$51").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Shift 3"


Range("A8:J10").Copy
Worksheets("Sorter").AutoFilterMode = False
Range("A30  ").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

UPDATE: Here is the exact code I am using now. It works very well to sort all of the data but does not seperate into groups.

```
Sub test02()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range

    ~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tracker")

    With ws
        .Columns("A:J").Sort Key1:=.Range("C1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _`
        `DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

        Set aCell = .Columns(3).Find(What:="Shift2")

       If Not aCell Is Nothing Then .Rows(aCell.Row).Insert

         Set aCell = .Columns(3).Find(What:="Shift3")

      If Not aCell Is Nothing Then .Rows(aCell.Row).Insert
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So, if you were going to do this manually, you would just sort by shift, then  stick a space in between each distinct shift group?

Comment: Yes, manually you would filter by each shift, and move the data where each group was separated by a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        .Columns("A:J").Sort Key1:=.Range("C1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

        Set aCell = .Columns(3).Find(What:="Shift2")

        .Rows(aCell.Row).Insert

        Set aCell = .Columns(3).Find(What:="Shift3")

        .Rows(aCell.Row).Insert
    End With
End Sub
```

**My Assumption**

Col 3 has all three words `Shift1`, `Shift2`, `Shift3`. If not then you will have to use `If aCell is Nothing` check.

**Logic**

1. Sort the columns
2. Find the first occurrence of `Shift2`
3. Insert the blank row
4. Find the first occurrence of `Shift3`
5. Insert the blank row

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do, thank you! However after modifying the names to fit my variables, I keep running into and error with the line    `.Rows(aCell.Row).Insert`                                            saying that "object variable or with block variable not set. Do you know what this really means?

Comment: Yup. :) see my assumptions part. if Shift2 or Shift3 are missing then you will have to use `if aCell is Nothing` check

Comment: Change `.Rows(aCell.Row).Insert` to `If Not aCell is Nothing then .Rows(aCell.Row).Insert`

Comment: The code works great for sorting the data! I am having trouble getting it to insert a row to separate groups, but I will keep trying. Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the exact code that you are using in the queston?

Comment: Yes, its pretty much your code exactly, just with modified sheet names. I just added it to the original question!

Comment: What happens if you change `Set aCell = .Columns(3).Find(What:="Shift2")` to `Set aCell = .Columns(3).Find(What:="Shift2", LookIn:=xlValues,   LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext,     MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)`

Comment: Worked great! I think the issue was that in my data, there is a space between Shift and #, thanks again for all your help~